# HTML allow only number without dot (.) in <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex, validation

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" required="" pattern="\d*" id="mobile">
```

**jQuery**

```
var letters = /^[0-9]+$/;
var mobile_backup="";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#mobile").on("input", function(){
        var mobile_value=$(this).val();
        if(mobile_value==="")
        {
            mobile_backup=mobile_value;
        }
        else if(mobile_value.match(letters)===null){
            $(this).val(mobile_backup);
        }
        else{
            mobile_backup=mobile_value;
        }
    });
});
```

Current solution works in all devices (desktop, mobile, tablet).
Is there any efficient approach available such that it works in all devices?

I know I can use a pattern for number. But I don't want an alert. I just want to allow the numbers without a dot.

Comment: `var letters = /^[0-9]+$/;` is **very** confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pattern attribute to add regex expression in html tag.
Try below code:

```
<form action="home_page.php">
    <label for="roll_no">Roll Number:</label>
    <input type="number" id="roll" name="roll" pattern="^[\d]+$"  title="Write your roll number"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Note :

1. The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Safari 10 (or earlier).
2. Validation of pattern attribute will not prevent from writing in the field but it will prevent from submitting form.

Comment: Already mentioned. "I know I can use a pattern for number."

Comment: Why do you put `\d` in a character class, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Toto that is used to open only numeric keypad in some devices. For me, on the iPhone, I have used it to open the numeric keypad.

Answer (score 0):

try `step="any"`
This allows a decimal point

Comment: I want without a decimal point.